# Wait for RabbitTemplate Correlated confirms

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have this function in RabbitMQ class that is used to publish messages:

```
    @Retryable(value = { AmqpIOException.class, AmqpTimeoutException.class, AmqpConnectException.class, AmqpReplyTimeoutException.class },
            maxAttempts = 3,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public void publish(Message msg, SuccessCallback<? super CorrelationData.Confirm> successCallback, FailureCallback failureCallback, String customRoutingKey) {
        CorrelationData data = new CorrelationData();
        data.getFuture().addCallback(successCallback, failureCallback);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(), customRoutingKey, msg, data);
    }
```

And here is how I use this function above:

```
public void sendMessageToRMQ(MyEntity msgObj, String routingKey) throws ServiceUnavailableException {

        try {
            rmqPublisher.publish(
                    MessageBuilder
                            .withBody(RMQPayloadBuilder.buildPayload(msgObj))
                            .build(),
                    confirmation -> {
                        if (confirmation != null && confirmation.isAck()) {
                            msgObj.setSentDate(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));

                            repository.save(msgObj);
                        } else {
                            StructuredLogger.logErrorMessage("Message un-ack", logValues);
                        }
                    },
                    failure -> StructuredLogger.logErrorMessage("un able to send", logValues),
                    routingKey
            );
        } catch (AmqpException amqpException) {
            StructuredLogger.logErrorMessage("Unable to publish message", logValues);
        }
    }
```

The the above function is used in a for loop to publish messages for huge number of msgObjects.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
// msgObjArray is a chunk of the whole msgObjArray

for (MyEntity msgObj : msgObjArrayChunk) {
            try {
                
                this.service.sendMessageToRMQ(msgObj, this.routingKey);


            } catch (ServiceUnavailableException e) {

                StructuredLogger.logErrorMessage("Failed to send ");
            }
        }

// What Should I write here to wait for the above chunk of msgObj to be acked and finished processing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `CorrelationData` from `publish` and collect them into a list; then, after the sends are complete, iterate over them and use `data.getFuture().get( <some timeout> )` to wait for each confirm.

Comment: So you mean the publish function remains as it is, and after `convertAndSend`call, I should return the `data`object, right? . And the data.getFuture.AddCallbacks does not change.

Comment: Yes, return the `CorrelationData`. And, it depends on what you are doing in your callback. You only need to add a callback if you want to receive the send result/failure asynchronously. Since you want to wait for the results on the sending thread, the callback is superfluous, unless you want to do something like debug logging there. Adding a callback does not remove the ability to block waiting for the future to complete.

Comment: Thanks That helped a lot. And yes I need the callback, after I get the ack, I have some business logic to execute.

Comment: Sorry to ask again. Is there any way to leverage the CompletableFuture interface instead of Future using CorrelationData ?

Comment: No; the `CorrelationData` uses Spring's `SettableListenableFuture` which is similar to `CompletableFuture`. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I have asked this new question with a big picture of what I am trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290564/handle-parallel-async-operations-with-futures-in-spring-app

Comment: It is still not clear what the problem is; the framework completes the future in the `CorrelationData` when the confirm is received; your code doesn't need to understand the type of future, just wait for the completion (or failure).